# Runtine error with angular 9 : Strict mode code may not include a with statement

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

After updating the visual studio tempalte for angular to version 9 I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement `:4200/vendor.js:137544`
```

The only appearance of strict is:

```
"strict-uri-encode": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/strict-uri-encode/-/strict-uri-encode-1.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-J5siXfHVgrH1TmWt3UNS4Y+qBxM=",
      "dev": true
```

[image: failing code]

After deleting the sloppy package I also get this console output

```
npm WARN @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@8.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@8.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@8.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-server@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.1 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Output after trying to delete domino:

```
C:\Users\user\Test\ClientApp>npm uninstall domino
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to C:\Users\user\Test\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\router
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@8.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@8.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@8.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-server@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\Test\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\router
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, access 'C:\Users\user\Test\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\router'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, access 'C:\Users\user\Test\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\router'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, access 'C:\\Users\\user\\Test\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\@angular\\router'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Test\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\@angular\\router'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-28T09_57_11_553Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you used "use strict" anywhere in your code? in .ts files?

Comment: I have no strict in my ts files. Its a fresh angular template from aspnetcore, which i updatet from angular 8 to 9

Comment: Can you provide the screen shot of vendor.js line number 137544? It is something with one of npm packages.

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: Do one thing: remove the sloppy.js package and install it again! It will solve the issue.

Comment: I did npm uninstall sloppy and npm install sloppy. I still get the same error

Comment: But i also get some warnings. I added them to the question

Comment: Can you uninstall and install the domino package as well? It is working fine on my end with angular 9

Comment: uninstalling domino throws me error. I added the ouput to the question.

Comment: try with sudo command

Comment: I'm on windows and already tried to run the command line as admin

Comment: ok my bad, package.json was opened somewhere. After deininstall domino und install domino i still get the same error as above.

Answer (score 2):

comment out this line

```
//export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

in **main.ts** may make it work

Comment: Hi Wei, it is not clear what you are asking... however, 'import {renderModule} from '@angular/platform-server' is more likely to work than 'export {renderModule from '@angular/platform-server'